# Is there a way to get Uncertainty/Vote output in Python OpenCV HoughCircles function

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm writing a code for circle detection in an image, where there are different types of circles (partial circles). I am using HoughCircles function in OpenCV python to detect the circles. But few partial circles are also detected along with the complete ones. Is there a way to know the Uncertainty value/votes for each detection.

A similar question is asked in the following [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/202770/uncertainty-output-in-houghcircles-function/), but I cannot use it in OpenCV python to get the vote value.

[image]

The left circle is a complete circle and the right one is a semi-circle(circles are slightly shifted because of blurring and pre-processing). I want to differentiate between the two using the vote value.

I am using **Python 3.6.10** and **OpenCV 4.2.0**

Comment: The docs say `circles Output vector of found circles. Each vector is encoded as 3 or 4 element floating-point vector (x,y,radius) or (x,y,radius,votes) .`  The votes should tell you what you want?  Why can you not use that?

Comment: Yes, That option I tried, works very well in c++. But, I could not get the same in python. Can you suggest to me a way to get this vote value in python?

Comment: I have not used the OpenCV version of Hough Circles. But the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d seem to indicate that HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT method and setting Param2 might return that value for the latest version of OpenCV (4.3?)

Comment: I tried using the **HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT** method, but it is throwing error that there is no attribute **HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT**. Also, I found this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles), where it's written that only **HOUGH_GRADIENT** method is implemented.

Comment: As I said above, I think that option is only available in OpenCV 4.3. See the 4.3 docs. `In the case of HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT algorithm, this is the circle "perfectness" measure. The closer it to 1, the better shaped circles algorithm selects. In most cases 0.9 should be fine. If you want get better detection of small circles, you may decrease it to 0.85, 0.8 or even less. But then also try to limit the search range [minRadius, maxRadius] to avoid many false circles.` It does not say that for OpenCV 4.2.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the version number. I will check if this can be done by changing the version.